# Security issues in Premium Theme

Tags: jquery, security

I purchased a premium HTML template from ThemeForest. I am using it for one of my projects.

I created a signup form using template element and I get a warning in the console stating

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://url_of_my_site' 
was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form which targets an insecure endpoint
'http://mrare.us8.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=77142ece814d3cff52058a51f&id=f300c9cce8&c=?'.
This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection
```

Found at: jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4

I have not sending any data to this endpoint. Is this a security breach and template author is recording our user inputs?

What can I do now?

.

Answer (score 1):

That its because your page was loaded over `https` protocol, but the form you post the data is with `http` protocol. You should instead set both to `https` or in the worst of the cases use both http

Comment: you failed to understand the question. I am not sending any data to that url. I believe template author is breaching security and recording my user inputs by malfunctioning JavaScript.

Comment: With the information provided its hard to tell, but if your endpoint is not yours, it has a high probability. If you can share an endpoint to take a look would be better

Comment: http://mrare.us8.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=77142ece814d3cff52058a51f&id=f300c9cce8&c=?

Comment: I mean, your site, where your template is showing, in order to search when the form is fired and what data is sending

Comment: It's not that your sending anything. It's the fact that the form action is there with an action attribute that points to an http only URL.

Comment: mrare.us8.list-manage.com throws an message about mailchimp, that its a marketing service